# Error while storing phone numbers in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have some phone numbers (validated such that all containing only integers, no `-` or `+` in them) as strings in a text file.

I am doing a simple mysql update on a mysql table which has phone number column as int(12). Note that I convert each phone number extracted from the text file to integer using intval().

The problem that I am facing is that instead of the numbers being inserted I just get **2147483647** to be inserted in each column. I guess I am making a small silly mistake somewhere, but still I can't figure it out. Can anyone explain what mistake am I making?

**EDIT:** Here is my the piece of code I am using (It does not give any sql error):

```
$sql="UPDATE ".$table." SET mobile = ".intval($smob).", phone = ".intval($sphone)." WHERE roll='".$sroll."'";
mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to insert the data?

Comment: The 2147483647 value will be entered into a column when the length of the number exceeds the maximum length for that data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from `intval()` manual:

> The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is 9223372036854775807.

What you are getting is a maximum number for signed integer on a 32bit machine.

I would strongly advise you to not use this function for phone number conversions. One of the simple reasons is that my mobile number is 11 digit number (without leading + or double zero for international access), and I believe there are some countries that have even more digits.

Why you would need to store phone numbers as `int`'s? Since most likely you are not doing some calculations and statistics on who might have a biggest phone number among your clients, and this data is probably used only for invoicing or a contact info, you could just leave that as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Phone numbers **are not integers**, and should not be stored using an integer type.

The observed behaviour happens because the values you are trying to store are outside the range accepted by the column type. I recommend putting MySQL into strict mode - this forces it to return errors when inserted data, etc. cannot be stored, instead of silently trying to do whatever is the least bad thing without failing.